# Transactional Service Layer with remote service invocations

Tags: database, spring, remote-server, transactional

The answer can be general covering all frameworks, but I am specifically interested in Spring MVC case. I am refactoring a service layer which is accessing internal database and a remote service/s. The methods should be transactional and they need the data from the remote services. Here is the similar dummy code:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository1;

    @Autowired
    private OtherRepository repository2;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteGateway remoteGateway;

    @Transactional
    public void updateState(Long id) {
        Item item1 = repository1.get(id)
        item1.setSomeVal(remoteGateway.getValue());
        repository1.save();

        repository2.doSomethingElse(item1.getOtherVal());
    }
}
```

It is easier to implement in this way. But has many downsides such as unnecessarily created and rolled back transactions when remote service call fails, longer transactions because of remote service call and may be more. I am thinking of moving service call to separate non-transactional method and calling the transactional method like is done in the following snippet

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private SomeRepository repository1;

    @Autowired
    private OtherRepository repository2;

    @Autowired
    private RemoteGateway remoteGateway;

    public SomeType updateState(Long id) {
        SomeType valueFromRemote = remoteGateway.getValue();
        updateState(id, valueFromRemote);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void updateState(Long id, SomeType valueFromRemote) {
        Item item1 = repository1.get(id)
        item1.setSomeVal(valueFromRemote);
        repository1.save();

        repository2.doSomethingElse(item1.getOtherVal());
    }
}
```

Assuming that remoteGateway have caching, proper timeouts, circuit breaker so that will not hang indefinitely and will be faster when value was already asked in the caching interval, will refactoring make sense? Or What can be a better design decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good refactoring if the length if transaction is a problem and if you know what values you will need in the transactional method before calling it. If you need to fetch many values from the remote service, you can consider calling the service asynchronously.

There is just one catch - if you use the default "proxy" way of transaction support, it doesn't work if you call a method of the same bean. In your case, calling `updateState(id, valueFromRemote)` from `updateState(Long id)` will not run in transaction, because there will be no proxy code executed (you can see the proxy support in a call stack when debugging a transactional method). To get around it, you can either

- move the transactional method to another bean
- or use the transactionManager in aspectj mode. See the [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I din't know about the catch you have mentioned. I really like to go with annotation approach. So after refactoring I will have two service layers. I assume it is ok to have two service layers for cases like this

Comment: With creating a new service layer, I would probably do it only if the vast majority of service methods need some remote data, otherwise you may end up creating methods that just delegate calls to a lower layer. You can postpone the decision till you know for sure that it's worth it.